# Auto populate current user information

Tags: user-profile-service

I am creating a list where I would like the current user information to auto populate so they don't have to type things like name, email, phone, etc. I have tried to do this in infopath but out system does not support the program. Is there any other way to do this? I am a newbie at sharepoint so please explain so I can understand.

thank you!

Comment: Are you using SP2013?

Comment: Yes, it's sharepoint 2013

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript:

```
var clientContext;
var user;

// Make sure the SharePoint script file 'sp.js' is loaded before your
// code runs.
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', sharePointReady);

function sharePointReady() {
    clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    user = clientContext.get_web().get_currentUser();

    clientContext.load(user);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
}
function onQuerySucceeded() {
    alert('The email address of the current user is ' + user.get_email());
    alert('The account name is ' + user.get_loginName());
}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Error: ' + args.get_message());
}
```

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245596.aspx)

Comment: I'm very new to programming and all the the terms. What is the sp.js and how do I make sure that it is loaded? To input this do I just go to the page that the list was on?

Comment: You can add a javascript file using the content web part.

You can do this by

Edit page -> Add web part -> Media and content -> Content editor -> Add.

Edit the source of the web part and add the following code into it: `<script src="/sites/subsite/list/SiteAssets/file.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> ` .  Add the js file under Site Assets using SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to editing your newform.aspx, you can acheive this using JSOM (to fetch user profile information):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/SP.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/SP.UserProfiles.js"></script>
<script src="/SiteAssets/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {   
      var personProperties;

      SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getCurrentUser, 'SP.UserProfiles.js');

      function getCurrentUser() {
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        personProperties = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext).getMyProperties();
        clientContext.load(personProperties);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(gotAccount, requestFailed);
      }

      function gotAccount(sender, args) {
        $('input[title="Name"]').val(personProperties.get_displayName());
      }

      function requestFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Cannot get user account information: ' + args.get_message());
      }
    });  
    </script>
```

Comment: Does this have to be done in sharepoint designer?